# how to click automatically element of c# web browser

Tags: c#

this is the html code

```
<span class="vi-atw-txt">Add to watch list</span>
```

I use following code to click it

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("vi-atw-txt").InvokeMember("click");
```

but it showing a nullreferenceexception...

what should i do?

Comment: You are doing get element by ID.  You are using the element's class.

Comment: there is not a method call getlementbyclass

Comment: Correct, so you need to use something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461932/how-to-getelement-by-class

Comment: it is little bit difficult to understand

Comment: I have elaborated in my example, please follow up with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a classname into GetElementById which will not work. C# does not offer a method to search by class name directly, but you can try the solution in [How to getelement by class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461932/how-to-getelement-by-class) except with a span as the tag to search for, and then fire the click when your class matches.

```
var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "vi-atw-txt")
    {
        link.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

What this code will do is create a collection of all spans, and then search through those spans until it finds a span with a classname of "vi-atw-txt".  Once that is found, it will call click on that span.

Comment: thanks. i need little more something to ask.. i need to click and wait 3 seconds and move to the next line of code. tell me how to do it..

Comment: The most direct way would be System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

Comment: The code I provided will stop execution for 3 seconds before allowing it to move forward.  If you need to do all of this code separately from the UI thread, then you should put all of it in a separate thread.

Comment: i don't know how to do it..  i am executing these on a timer1_tick
https://scontent.fcmb1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/26114143_159366131495805_607926980461952724_n.jpg?oh=e9277efc396e50fc60700a9500a05c7e&oe=5AB0DA30

Answer (score 0):

To use the method getElementById you would have to add an id to the span tag:

```
<span id="someid" class="vi-atw-txt">Add to watch list</span>
```

Then:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("someid").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: I'm assuming the OP does not control the page they are browsing with the webBrowser object, and can therefore not arbitrarily add Ids.

Comment: Good point, obviously this answer is only relevant if the user can edit the html (which they don't specify).